# shape and size of power plugs

Tags: power, plug, socket

What is the reason behind designing electronic devices with power cords that do not fit side by side on power boards or wall sockets.

For example: all power boards that I've seen (for home/office use) and wall sockets in my house/work all have the same distance between each socket.

Yet I have seen many devices that cannot plug into sockets side by side: the plug (wall warts) takes space of 1.5 socket (is it not possible to build a circuit board smaller?) or the cable of the plug point down and blocks the socket bellow (vertical sockets on the wall) or some plugs have wire going sideways and block a socket in horizontal line.

Can somebody explain why it is designed this way? Does the size and direction on cable effect functionality in any way? If tese were built this way for a reason, what is it?

P.S.
As someone mentioned there are industrial standards that will allow any everyday plugs to fit; is this solution drastically different to office/home solutions (different load/voltage/current/etc)?

I am in New Zealand, but I have been in Europe/Australia and their sockets are at the same distances from each other. And with most power boards made in China I assume they are common around the world and are not specific to my country.

Comment: There are many socket types around the world. Which country or socket you are talking about? Your modem most likely has a socket pluggable power supply, not a mains plug. Power supplies are big so they are bigger than a simple plug. But you can take a picture of course for us to see.

Comment: This is just a rant. Do you have an actual design question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a very general question about the size and shape of products in the market place. It is not a specific question about electrical engineering design or theory. This question is more about market forces than anything else.

Comment: Socket designers cannot see the future nor can they predict things the  minimum size something in the future can be made.

Comment: Closed? Another shameful act by the no-fun league. This brought an interesting and lively discussion.

Comment: The question posed is, "Socket spacing seems to have a standard, why not make plugs that fit side by side?" Seems pretty clear, with a straightforward answer (wall warts).

Answer (score 1):

That's just the power strip builders trying to be economical with space.

On the other hand, it is also *you* being economical with power strips.  Better quality power strips do, in fact, put some sockets at farther-apart spacing.

You can also get things like Legrand Plugmold multi-outlet strips, which are designed to run for several feet along a wall, and provide sockets at a particular spacing - every 6", every 3", etc. Those are also available as cord-and-plug arrangements e.g. for installation on a computer desk.  (of course they're not Chinese cheap).

- A fun thing about the Plugmold style permanently installed multi-outlet strips, is that they **count as 1 receptacle** in jurisdictions that limit the number of receptacles per circuit... e.g. some limit you to 8 receps on a 15A circuit and 12 receps on a 20A circuit.  Well, a 10 foot long Plugmold installation with 20 sockets counts as 1 recep.
- These are also UL-listed and built to an industrial standard so yeah, you can plug heaters into em!

[image]
[image]

Comment: "it is also you being economical with power strips" after reading this I checked the store and you are absolutely right, the strip for $5 has poor spacing, the one for $90 is designed smarter and solves the issue. I'll see if I can find a wall plate socket with better design too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the plug - they fit side-by-side just fine. It's cheapo wall warts, which are an abomination. They always have this issue when using a power strip. A short extension cord fixes it, kinda.

That said, some clever designers figured out that if you tilt the power strip sockets at an angle, it helps with this problem - I've seen this mostly on strips for euro type (Schuko) plugs.

Like this:

[image]

Another approach is the 'octopus' cable:

[image]

Quite possibly even more ugly, and expensive, but... functional.

Comment: Honestly, I beg to differ about wall warts.  Wall warts mean **innovation doesn't come at the expense of safety**.  EEs can knock out a million cool products and breeze through UL listing (or skip it) because they operate entirely on low current low voltage DC. And use any commodity wall wart for the mains AC.  And the UL-listed ones glut the market to the point where it's not worth the risk smuggling in dangerous cheapies.

Comment: Not arguing that wall warts serve a *function*. But the adapters that are cheapest - the ones with big off-the-line transformers - take up way more space than they have a right to. That's what makes them an abomination. At least now the ubiquitous mobile phone charger has changed the game somewhat, with the expectation that the adapter won't consume more space than the plug. I get your point about crappy ones though.

Comment: +1 for the squid.  That's exactly what I use for my external USB drives.